# Use applescript to resize a window in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, resize, window, applescript

This is one of my first times using Xcode/AppleScript in my life - so sorry if very stupid question.  Anyway, I have a little test window under my MainMenu.xib file.  I've set up a tab view with different buttons and things under each tab that have all sorts of random test functions (displaying dialogs, saying things, requesting passwords, etc.).  In one tab, I want to have a lot of test content, but in another tab I only want a little.  Is it possible, when you change tab, to have it resize the window to specified dimensions?  Also, I've made my window un-resizeable (otherwise the formatting gets all messed up when resized), and would it be possible to allow this resizing, even if you can't resize with the mouse?  Sorry if this doesn't make any sense, I'll be happy to clarify should anyone need it.  Any help would be appreciated, I've been googling for quite a bit.

Comment: It sounds like you want the same behaviour of the system preferences. They shrink or expand deepening on tab content. Yes it is possible. But it seems to me you need to first look at how the anchoring works first so you formatting does not get messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resize windows in applescript, you can use this command:

```
tell current application to set the bounds of the front window to {24, 96, 524, 396}
```

So if you want to activate such a script, put this in your AppDelegate.applescript:

```
on tabclick1_(aNotification)
    tell current application to set the bounds of the front window to {24, 96, 524, 396}
end tabclick1_
```

You can then connect this to a tab button, and set the bounds of the window as you like.

You can, of course copy this, but then change the name "tabclick1_", and the bounds, and then connect it to another tab.
So each time you click a tab, it will activate its appropriate script (for example "tabclick1_"), and that script will change the bounds of the window.

But you will have to make your window resizable, and anchor your objects correctly.

*Important:*

1. The first item of the bounds is the distance in pixels from the left side of your screen to the left side of your window.
2. The second item of the bounds is the distance in pixels from the top of your screen to the top of your window.
3. The third item of the bounds is the distance in pixels from the left side of your screen to the right side of your window.
4. The fourth item of the bounds is the distance in pixels from the top of your screen to the bottom of your window.

Comment: Yes, but do you know how to do it if your window isn't resizable?

Comment: You could check wether the window is resizable, and if it isn't make it resizable and after you changed the bounds, you can make it unresizable again. You will need Cocoa commands though.