# Is there a way to get current active app on Mac OS X using shell script

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I want to run a CRON job which will identify currently active window and log it to some file. Is there a way through shell script to identify the currently active window on Mac?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get name of frontmost app with AppleScript and use it to get the filepath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613293/how-to-get-name-of-frontmost-app-with-applescript-and-use-it-to-get-the-filepath)